# Clojure How to Expand Macro in Source File Versus Repl

Tags: macros, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I am leaning macros in Clojure and have a question about macro expansion.  In the repl, when I do this:

```
user=> (defmacro unless [pred a b] `(if (not ~pred) ~a ~b))
#'user/unless
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(unless (> 5 3) :foo :bar))
(if (clojure.core/not (> 5 3)) :foo :bar)
```

But when I do the same in a clj file:

```
(ns scratch-pad.core
     (:gen-class))

(defmacro unless [pred a b]
    `(if (not ~pred) ~a ~b))

(defn -main [& args]
    (prn
        (macroexpand-1 '(unless (> 5 3) :foo :bar))))
```

and run the code, I get this:

```
$ lein run
(unless (> 5 3) :foo :bar)
```

How do I get the code to print the same as the repl?

Comment: I think the sarcastic version of the answer is "fix the bug in clojure and submit a pull request". The behavior is inconsistent and does not seem to be documented or intentional. Bug reproducible in clojure versions 1.3, 1.4, 1.5

Comment: Unfortunately, sarcastic or not, any actual pull requests will be ignored, I think; instead you must sign the CA (on actual paper) and submit patches via Jira -- http://clojure.org/contributing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What's going on

This happens because of how the notion of the current namespace works in Clojure. `macroexpand-1` expands its argument in the current namespace.

At the REPL, this will be `user`; you're defining the macro in the `user` namespace, then you call `macroexpand-1` in that namespace and all is good.

In a `:gen-class'd` namespace, or indeed any other namespace, the compilation-time current namespace is that namespace itself. When you later call the code defined in this namespace, however, the then-current namespace will be whatever is appropriate at that point. That might be some other namespace as it gets compiled.

Finally, at your app's runtime, the default current namespace is `user`.

To see this, you could move the macro to a separate namespace also defining a function `use-the-macro` and calling this function at top level; the `:gen-class`'d namespace would then need to require or use the macro's namespace. Then `lein run` will print what you expect once (at the macro's namespace's compilation time) and the unexpanded form twice (when the macro's namespace is `require`d by the main namespace and then when `-main` calls `use-the-macro`).

#### Solutions

The Clojure REPL controls the current namespace using `binding`; you can do the same:

```
(binding [*ns* (the-ns 'scratchpad.core)]
  (prn (macroexpand-1 ...)))
```

You can also use syntax-quote instead of quote in `-main`:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (prn (macroexpand-1 `...)))
                      ^- changed this
```

Of course if symbols other than `unless` were involved, you'd have to decide whether they should be namespace-qualified in the output and possibly prefix them with `~'`. This is the point though -- syntax-quote is good for producing mostly "namespace-independent" code (which is what makes it so great for writing macros, besides the convenient syntax).

Another possible "fix" (tested on Clojure 1.5.1) is adding an `in-ns` call to `-main`:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (in-ns 'scratchpad.core)
  (prn (macroexpand-1 '...)))
                      ^- no change here this time
```

As with `binding`, this way you're actually getting the expansion of your original form in your original namespace.

Comment: how is it that you would need to specify in-ns in a function, when it is already in that namespace? this behavior is very confusing. Also, without any unquote being used, ` should behave exactly like '. I think this is a nice workaround, but the underlying issue is a bug.

Comment: You're wrong about syntax-quote (backtick) vs. quote -- in Clojure, syntax-quoting causes non-namespace-qualified symbols to be replaced with their namespace-qualified counterparts (as resolved in the read-time namespace). This is a different, though of course similar, mechanism to quasiquotation in other Lisps. About the behaviour described in the question being confusing -- sure, I'll grant that. I'll see if it's a bug and maybe write a fix. In case it's not considered critical enough to release a hotfix release *right now* (which I guess it might not be), here are the workarounds for now.

Comment: Also, please note that I already said I think this behaviour is surprising and I'll be looking into it some more in the answer, calling the snippets "workarounds". There isn't much more I can say to your "how is it..." question, really. As a side note: to me, this is surprising *given my expectations about which namespace the code will run in*, which I thought matched the docs on `gen-class`; it's clear that `macroexpand-1` will produce different results in different contexts (depending on which macros are visible in the current namespace).

Comment: No worries. Edited the answer with a proper explanation after giving this a little more thought. Basically I was surprised at first, but now it totally seems like expected behaviour to me. Perhaps the runtime default current ns issue could use better docs though.

Comment: why is it that changing namespace alters the way that macroexpand / macroexpand-1 / clojure.walk/macroexpand-all behave? what about being in a different namespace prevents the expansion? another workaround to this issue: (macroexpand-1 '(scratch-pad.core/unless ...)) - fully qualifying in the quoted form makes the runtime expansion when called from another namespace work properly

Comment: It's not `macroexpand-*` in particular, it's just that `macroexpand-1` uses the regular mechanism for resolving symbols to Vars and that depends on the current ns (the other `macroexpand`s delegate to `macroexpand-1`). (Which is what allows you to write `(defn foo [] (bar))` without explicitly namespace-qualifying `bar` when `bar` is a the name of a Var or an alias in the current namespace.) Agreed that your workaround will work; syntax-quote does the same thing for all symbols in non-unquoted portions of the form (except `foo#` which is shorthand for a certain pattern of using `gensym`).

Comment: @Michal this seemed to work for me based on your solution 2: `(defn -main [& args]
    (in-ns 'scratch-pad.core)
    (prn
        (macroexpand-1 \`(unless (> 5 3) :foo :bar))))`  thanks for the answer

Comment: @DavidWilliams No problem. You shouldn't need to use both syntax-quote and `in-ns`, though. Actually I now realize that I forgot about what's probably the best solution all around, which is to use `(binding [*ns* your-preferred-namespace] (macroexpand-1 ...))`; Clojure's REPL uses `(binding [*ns* ...] ...)` to control the current namespace.

Comment: Edited the answer to add the `binding` solution, as well as to move the quotes to where they belong; also rephrased some parts a bit while I was at it.